Can Sherlock Holmes be convicted of killing Dr. Grimesby Roylott?
Inspired by The Adventure of the Speckled Band. The following description contains SPOILERS.
Near the end of the story, Dr. Roylott sends a venomous snake down a rope with Holmes on the other end. Holmes was expecting the snake, so he struck the rope (and possibly the snake) with a cane. Agitated, the snake turned around and attacked Dr. Roylott, who was killed.
Holmes says in the last sentence of the story that:

In this way I am no doubt indirectly responsible for Dr. Grimesby Roylott's death, and I cannot say that it is likely to weigh very heavily upon my conscience.

If Holmes had been charged with causing Dr. Roylott's death, would he have been found guilty?

I don't think there are poisonous snakes in England. Without deeper knowledge of the story, I guess the victim brought the snake themselves? It wasn't just sitting on the rope minding it's own business?

@nvoigt (MORE SPOILERS) Dr. Roylott got the snake from a foreign country. He sent the snake to kill someone, but Holmes anticipated it and removed that someone from the scene.

@nvoigt As a public service announcement in general (and not directed at you), snakes are venomous and not poisonous.  They could only be poisonous if you eat them.   But (and this is for you!) there is one venomous snake in Great Britain, the adder - however it is not considered deadly to humans.  And it is Ireland that doesn't have any snakes at all.

@nvoigt Quote: "The adder — UK's only venomous snake The adder is the UK's biggest venomous animal, but they are rarely a threat to people or dogs. It is one of three native snakes in the UK, along with the grass snake and smooth snake." https://www.zsl.org/what-we-do/species/adder

There are dangerous snakes in the UK that are not native to the UK. For example, London Zoo has some king cobra and Mangshan pit vipers.  /pedant.

Isn't this similar to someone pointing a gun at me with the intent to shoot me, and me knocking the gun out of his hand which then falls to the ground, discharges, and accidentally kills my assailant?

@Peter M, actually a biologist of my acquaintance told me that "poisonous" is correct. Venomous is more precise, but anything that contains poison is poisonous.  A snake that kills you by biting you is venomous. A mushroom that kills you if you eat it is toxic. But they are both poisonous.

Maybe involuntary manslaughter
Murder is off the table because Holmes lacked the intent to cause Dr. Roylott’s death, and was not engaged in a felony at the time (he was in the room at the invitation of its legal occupant).
To prove manslaughter, the Crown would need to prove recklessness or gross (criminal) negligence on the part of Holmes. Neither seems likely.

Holmes suspected that the vector of Dr. Roylott’s murderous intent was a snake, and he deliberately chose to confirm this. There seems to have been little else he could do as there was clearly insufficient evidence for a search warrant, even if he were a policeman.


He then struck at the snake with his cane in self-defence - which is a complete defence to murder or manslaughter - after which it retreated and bit its owner.

I can’t see anything reckless here. Nor is the outcome reasonably foreseeable, which even normal negligence needs.

Which kinda begs the question: if it isn't "reasonable foreseeable" but you're Sherlock Holmes and did foresee it, then what?

His self-defence claim might be harmed by the fact that he was lying in wait, having persuaded the intended victim to stay away and positioned himself (and faithful Dr Watons) there in her stead. But no jury in the land would have convicted him.

@DonQuiKong As Inspector Lestrade would no doubt quite readily testify, "Sherlock Holmes" is veritably synonymous with "unreasonable"

@Lag The self-defense claim is still solid. He was there where the victim would have been, but he was not there with an intent to kill Dr. Roylott.

@Lag It might have more success as a wrongful death civil claim: Roylott, an incompetent snake handler who should have foresaw the victim fighting back, versus Holmes, somebody with poor professional judgement who failed to properly neutralize a dangerous animal.

Regardless of whether Holmes is reasonable or not, the test in English law is whether a reasonable person would foresee the event rather than whether a specific person (in this case the putative defendant) should foresee it.

Can it be argued that Holmes took actions that would increase the odds of someone dying? He could have, for example, stayed away from the bed (and hence the snake).

@Allure Only in a universe where being a bodyguard is illegal, given that is effectively the same thing.

Also, one might expect someone who uses venomous snakes as murder weapons would know how to handle it if the snake turned on them...

I consider it unlikely that Mr Holmes could have been charged.  As has already been stated, he was present in the room by invitation, and he would be able to claim that his actions were in self-defence and defence of others (Dr. Watson).
He would be able to claim that given Helen Stoner's testimony and his examination of the room showing that only a narrow vent existed between the rooms, he expected that the room would be invaded by a venomous creature such as a snake.
Since he did not expect that the offender (whoever he or she may be) would attempt to use this animal to commit another murder as he suspected  had already taken place in that bedroom if he did not leave the room unilluminated, he was only able to see movement in the dim light through the vent.
Given that he saw movement and had reason to believe that this lethally venomous animal was coming through the vent, he defended himself with his walking cane, an item of fashion that in the 19th century would have been made of sturdy timber and potentially also metal, and Holmes was known to be an expert in singlestick fighting with just such an implement.
Given Holmes' expertise and the likely weight of his cane, one solid blow to a venomous snake with such a weapon would be likely to cripple or kill it, or at the very least knock it from the imitation bell-rope down which it was climbing to a place where he could strike at it again with intent to kill it.
However, in the darkness, Holmes failed to strike the snake well enough to achieve his intent, and the animal was sufficiently fearful to retreat the way it had come, where it fatally bit its handler.
Therefore Dr Roylott's death from snakebite occured as a result of Mr Holmes' attempts at self-defence against a deadly threat that he had caused.  Mr Holmes could show that his response was proportional to the threat, and was not intended to harm any person.  It was a regrettable consequence that once the snake had retreated beyond reach of Mr Holmes' cane, Mr Holmes was unable to reach Dr Roylott or his snake before he was fatally bitten by the agitated animal that Mr Holmes was attempting to kill.
A jury hearing that Dr. Roylott (who had a criminal conviction with jail time in Commonwealth territories for an unlawful killing) had likley used his deadly venomous snake to murder one of his step-daughters and attempted to murder the other, and Mr Holmes' and his eyewitness Dr Watson's testimony that he was acting in self-defence when he attempted to kill the snake, would be very likely to find that Mr. Holmes had acted in self-defence and was therefore not guilty.
